# Android webView.loadUrl with quotes

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

With the below java and javascript code; I get an error on this line `document.getElementById('txtCardSwipePOS').value = "[SWIPED_CARD]";`. If I change the double quotes around `[SWIPED_CARD]` to single quotes it works.

But then if I have single quotes in my string it does NOT work. Ideally I want to have double quotes around `"[SWIPED_CARD]"` so the json encode works correctly; but it seems loading javascript via  a url with double quotes doesn't work. Is there a way around this?

```
    String creditCardSwipe = new String (cardData);

    creditCardSwipe = StoreWebActivity.jsonString(creditCardSwipe);
    String javascriptCode = "";
    try {
        javascriptCode = StoreWebActivity.convertStreamToString(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credit_card_swipe));
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int API = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    javascriptCode = javascriptCode.replace("[SWIPED_CARD]", creditCardSwipe);

    //old way of injecting javascript
    if (API < 19)
    {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+javascriptCode);
    }
    else //Android 19 or above
    {
        webView.evaluateJavascript(javascriptCode,null);
    }

    //Sometimes swipes can be detected as valid, but in reality aren't so request swipe again
    myUniMagReader.startSwipeCard();
    isWaitingForSwipe = true;
```

R.raw.credit_card_swipe (JS Loaded Above)

```
if (document.getElementById('txtCardSwipePOS'))
{
    document.getElementById('txtCardSwipePOS').value = "[SWIPED_CARD]";
}

if (document.getElementById('divProgressOverlay'))
{
    document.getElementById('divProgressOverlay').style.display = '';
}

if (document.getElementById('imgProgress'))
{
    ProgressImg = document.getElementById('imgProgress');
    setTimeout('ProgressImg.src = ProgressImg.src', 0);
}

if (document.getElementById('frmCheckout'))
{
    //Need to use setTimeout for form submission so loading indicators have time to display (this is for Android)
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        document.getElementById('frmCheckout').submit();
    },0);
}
```

Comment: how about str.replace("\"", "&#34;") and str.replace("'", "&#39;") for all the texts that you need to sanitize on the java side?  (first for double, second for single)

Comment: The problem is if any of the javascriptCode has a double quote in it; it causes issues. Is there a way around this? I think it is because of js code being initiated with javascript: XX Also the code you gave me is javascript I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when converting to json it added the double quotes automatically. So removing the quotes from js file fixed it.